# Angular js: Change the font color and image, based on json response

Tags: angularjs

Suppose their is an external json file:

```
{"threat": [{"level": "Low"},{"level": "Medium"},{"level": "high"}]}
```

And following is the HTML code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <h1>Page Title</h1>
   <img src="images/status.jpg">
   <p>change color</p>
</body>
```

How i can change image and p tag color? depending upon the json response (threat level).

1. High:red
2. Low:green
3. medium:orange

I am new to Angular js, tried some methods like ng-style and ng-if to change the styles. But dint work out.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    // Simple GET request example:
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'data/color.json'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        console.log(response);
          return response;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        console.log(response);
          return response;
      });
}
```

But i am getting undefined in console instead of response.

After getting response I have to check how to change image and text color?depending upon response high, Low and medium.

Comment: the question could be improved - add some JSON as a code instead of using list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make 3 css class for font-color

```
.red {
  color: 'red';
}
.green {
  color: 'green';
}
.orange {
  color: 'orange';
}
```

now you can do it in two different ways,

Option 1)

in js do:

```
$scope.selectedItem = ({Low:{
    url: '1images/status.jpg',
    class: 'green'
  },
  Medium:{
    url: '2images/status.jpg',
    class: 'orange'
  },
  High:{
    url: '3images/status.jpg',
    class: 'red'
  }
})[selectedResponse.level];
```

in HTML do

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <h1>Page Title</h1>
   <img src="{{selectedItem.url}}">
   <p class="{{selectedItem.class}}">change color</p>
</body>
```

Option 2)

In html use ng-class and ng-if:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  <img src="url1" ng-if="response.level === 'Low'">
  <img src="url2" ng-if="response.level === 'Medium'">
  <img src="url3" ng-if="response.level === 'High'">
  <p ng-class="{'red': response.level === 'High', 'orange': response.level === 'Medium', 'green': response.level === 'Low'}">change color</p>
</body>
```

Comment: What does [selectedResponse.level] do?

Comment: selectedResponse should be the selected object from you array of objects (`{"threat": [{"level": "Low"},{"level": "Medium"},{"level": "high"}]}`). So `[selectedResponse.level] = ['Low']` (if Low is selected). You can see an object before this line. So this will choose the value of 'Low' and assign to `$scope.selectedItem`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this multiple ways.

With ng-style:

```
<p ng-style="variableWithStyle">change color</p>
//variableWithStyle={color:'orange'}
//or
<p ng-style="{color:variableWithStyle}">change color</p>
//variableWithStyle='orange'
```

With ng-class

```
<p ng-class="variableWithClass">change color</p>
//variableWithClass='medium', medium is defined in .css
```

Comment: How I will get to know that the response from json is medium? and change the color to orange.

Comment: According to the json in original question 
`jsonVariable={"threat": [{"level": "Low"},{"level": "Medium"},{"level": "high"}]}`, from it you can extract desired object 
`variableWithStyle=jsonVariable['thread'][1]['level']`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this with **init=""** method

```
<body ng-app="myApp"  ng-init="High = 'red'; Low = 'green'; Medium = 'orange'">
   <h1>Page Title</h1>
   <img src="images/status.jpg">
   <p  style="color:{{threat.level}};">change color</p>
</body>
```

**Note:** check variable name will be case sensitive.